# NFS server and client on two Azure VMs, client unable to connect

Tags: azure, nfs, azure-virtual-machine

I have deployed a NFS server on an Azure Ubuntu 14.04LTS VM using this [tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo).

The problem that I'm facing is this: While I am able to successfully mount the folder I want when the client is my laptop or another physical machine, I can't do the same with another VM posing as a client.
I have configured the required endpoints (ports 2049 both udp and tcp) and I have, followed the exact same steps. What I get is this:

```
azureuser@testNode2:~$ sudo mount public.Azure.IP.ofNode1:export/users /export
mount.nfs: Connection timed out
```

I have also tried to mount using internal IP addresses but the outcome is the same.

If anyone could tell me what causes this or help me with this issue I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to open [TCP/UDP 111](https://serverfault.com/questions/377170/which-ports-do-i-need-to-open-in-the-firewall-to-use-nfs). If the two VMs are in Azure, you should make them part of the same cloud service, or connect them to a virtual network in which case given Ubuntu in Azure ships with no default software firewall you wouldn't need to open anything.

Comment: None of the VMs are connected to virtual network, yet those with internal ip addresses that have the first two octets in common (ie: VM1: A.B.C.D and VM2: A.B.E.F) do connect. Is there a way that I get my VMs to have internal addresses in the same class , without setting up a virtual network?

Comment: Not that I know of. When you create multiple VMs under the same cloud service they should (as you point out) reach each other but getting the same subnet seems to be hit and miss (maybe depending on DC?) but anyway those IPs are not guaranteed to be static anyway so the virtual network (whether Azure's or if you roll out your own OpenVPN for example) is important for persistence.